# How to get the users location using google maps v3

Tags: google-maps

I have been trying to get the users location using the map v3 and show the path from there location to a fixed destination. But i had no luck finding a solution to get the users location, i have read the API but couldn't figure out anything checked all the examples still the same . hope some one can help me Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var loc = {};
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if(google.loader.ClientLocation) {
        loc.lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
        loc.lng = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                alert(results[0]['formatted_address']);
            };
        });
    }
}

google.load("maps", "3.x", {other_params: "sensor=false", callback:initialize});
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply , but i cant get this to work, :( could you assist me please... im new to the Google maps.

Answer (score 0):

google.loader.ClientLocation only gives a very approximate estimate as to the user's location.

Best choice is to use that as a fallback if HTML5 geolocation is not present, or not allowed by the user.

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(p) {
        //get position from p.coords.latitude and p.coords.longitude
        },
        function() {
            //denied or error
            //use google.loader.ClientLocation
        }
    );
} else {
    //use google.loader.ClientLocation
}
```

Comment: Thanx Adam, i will try it but, since i am new to Google maps i have less understanding of how to use get current position and functions that are defined by Google...this is really emeberesing but isn't there a simpler way to do this only using the google map v3 , Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom':2,'center':new google.maps.LatLng(39.809734,-98.55562), 'callback': function() {

                var self = this; 
                self.getCurrentPosition(function(position, status) { 
                    if ( status === 'OK' ) {

                        clientlat = position.coords.latitude;
                        clientlon = position.coords.longitude;
                        var clientlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(clientlat, clientlon);

                    }
                });

          }});
```